# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: unknown column

Tags: mysql, jpa, entity

I have some hard time with my program. All I want is to get some objects from table that have this simple structure:

```
mysql> describe tb_rasa;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| nazwa  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| symbol | varchar(4)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

in my bean class I have:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {    
    rasa = rasaEJB.wyswietlRase(1);
}
```

in RasaEJB:

```
public RasaSl wyswietlRase(Integer id) {
    System.out.println("RasaEJB.wyswietlRase(id)");     
    RasaSl rasa = rasaDao.find(id);     
    return rasa;        
}
```

RasaSl entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_rasa")
 public class RasaSl implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4682401385263402475L;

@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column(name="nazwa",columnDefinition="varchar(50)")
private String nazwa;

@Column(name="symbol", columnDefinition="varchar(4)")
private String symbol;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="rasaSl", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<RasaStatystyka> modyfikatory = new ArrayList<RasaStatystyka>();

public String getNazwa() {
    return nazwa;
}

public void setNazwa(String nazwa) {
    this.nazwa = nazwa;
}

public String getSymbol() {
    return symbol;
}

public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
}

public List<RasaStatystyka> getModyfikatory() {
    return modyfikatory;
}

public void setModyfikatory(List<RasaStatystyka> modyfikatory) {
    this.modyfikatory = modyfikatory;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

I have completely know idea what could create this error:

```
RasaEJB.wyswietlRase(id)
[EL Info]: 2013-08-29 16:45:18.207--ServerSession(1816969462)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
[EL Info]: 2013-08-29 16:45:18.588--ServerSession(1816969462)--file:/D:/usr/java/moje/system/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp4/wtpwebapps/EclipseJPA2-war/WEB-INF/lib/EclipseJPA2-jpa-0.01.jar_persistenceUnit login successful
[EL Warning]: 2013-08-29 16:45:18.688--UnitOfWork(1358566974)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: SELECT id, nazwa, symbol FROM tb_rasa WHERE (id = ?)
bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="readRasaSl" referenceClass=RasaSl sql="SELECT id, nazwa, symbol FROM tb_rasa WHERE (id = ?)")
```

Please help.

Comment: are you sure your java code is accessing the same DB as the one you're using in the mysql monitor?

Comment: I had to be sure that the only problem here would be java code accessing the other DB, that this is the only way. You were right, the problem was in server configuration which pointed out the wrong DB. Thanks!